# Are the 1335 days of Daniel 12 actually years

Tags: eschatology, daniel

Was the building of the dome of the rock between 687-691the last cause of abomination that causes desolation? If the 1335 days of Daniel 12 are actually years, the next abomination may be 691AD + 1335 years i.e. 2026. We are looking for the man of lawlessness who makes a 7 year deal with Israel and stops the sacrifices half way through. Maybe both these events will co-incide, any thoughts